# Mounted usb pendrive on desktop

Tags: usb

I mounted my USB device on desktop and now I can't see what I have in it. I see my desktop as an USB device and I can't unmount it. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal, and run:

```
sudo umount /home/$USER/Desktop
```

(Adjust for your language if necessary)
This should unmount your USB drive and restore normal Desktop. If not, please, leave a comment.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please, if the question helped you, mark it as Accepted Answer with the green tick below vote number on the left.